# Python Scrapy allowed_damins Attriute

Tags: python, scrapy

I am studying with coding simple code, getting post information of stack over flow questions.

I set `allowed_domains = ["http://stackoverflow.com/questions/]` with a base Spider.
And its parse() Method only return a Request with the url of format. `"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/%d/" % no`

I thought it will work...maybe i have a misunderstanding on allowed_domain.
All requests returned by parse() seem filtered by allowed_domain.
It only works when i remove the allowed_domain.
Can you explain..? sorry about my trivial question.

```
class StackOverFlowPost(scrapy.Spider):
    startNo = 26200877
    endNo = 26200880
    curNo = 26200877
    name = "stackOverFlowPost"
    start_urls = ["http://stackoverflow.com/questions/%d/" % startNo ]
    allowed_domains = ["http://stackoverflow.com/questions"]
    baseUrl = "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/%d/"

    def parse(self, response):
        itemObj = items.StackOverFlowItem()

        # getting items information from the page
        ...
        yield itemObj

        StackOverFlowPost.curNo += 1
        nextPost = StackOverFlowPost.baseUrl % StackOverFlowPost.curNo  

        yield scrapy.Request(nextPost, callback = self.parse)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you spider, `allowed_domains` should be a list of `domain` (not `url`):

```
allowed_domains = ["stackoverflow.com"]
```

---

Notice that, you can also set `start_urls` with a list of `url`:

```
start_urls = ["http://stackoverflow.com/questions/%d/" % i for i in range(startNo, endNo+1)]
```

It makes `parse()` easy to write.

Comment: what is mean?, the allowed_domain is already a list. but as you said, if i change it to `"stackoverflow.com"`, it works, should i remove `"http"` and `"/question"` ? why ? sorry but can you explain more?